# memcpy code optimized with -Os because of limited buffer scope

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I have the following C code, which works fine without optimization (-O0) but has unexpected behavior when using -Os:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool functionA(uint8_t* ptr1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        ptr1[i] = i;
    }
    printf("functionA\n");
    return true;
}

static bool functionB(uint8_t* ptr1)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    uint8_t ptr2[16] = {0};

    if (functionA(ptr2))
    {
        retVal = true;
        memcpy(ptr1, ptr2, 16);
    }

    return retVal;
}


int main(void)
{
    const uint8_t* p = NULL;
    const uint8_t BUF[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            uint8_t buff32[32] = {0x5};

            if (functionB(buff32))
            {
                p = buff32;
                break;
            }

            continue;

        }
        else
        {
            p = BUF;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", p[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the code with  "-O0", I have the result:

```
functionA
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
```

However, with "-Os" or "-O3" (not "-O2"):

```
functionA
16 24 97 6b fc 7f 0 0 8d f2 b7 c ed 55 0 0
```

I tried on godbolt with different compilers like ARM GCC 10.3.1 and I see that the code of the memcpy in "functionB" is not compiled. Changing the scope of the `buff32` at the beginning of the `main` seems to solve the issue. It seems that GCC judges that the buffer is no longer used in its scope and considers it as unused, hence optimizes it.

Is it possible to get a warning from the compiler?
Is it an undefined behavior?

Comment: _"stack-use-after-scope"_ @ `printf("%x ", p[i]);` - Compile with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to catch these things

Comment: Btw, why have you repeated the whole question twice?

Comment: Another issue with this question is that I don't know what your question is.  Please clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing the first iteration of the loop if `functionB` is true then you assign the value of `buff32` to the variable `p`.
Now `p` points to the beginning of `buff32` that is an array on the stack. When you call `break` and exit the loop the stack frame is freed and so `p` points to a stack space that is not in use anymore.
If you move the definition of `buff32` out of the loop (like you said you did in the question) that space is valid until the program exits so you don't get that problem.

That is why the @Ted-Lyngmo comment says that the sanitizers report a `stack-use-after-scope`.

Comment: Actual C implementations don't normally change the stack pointer when entering / leaving a scope that didn't contain a variable-length array.  Just do allocation once for the whole function.  But since `BUF` and `buff32` won't actually both be pointed-to at the same time (by a program that doesn't have UB about about object lifetimes), the compiler might choose to overlap them or something like that, per the as-if rule.  Or since `p = buff32; break;` will directly lead to UB in the next loop, a compiler could assume that doesn't happen.  Except i==1 is guaranteed on the first iter.

Comment: If we look at x86-64 GCC's asm for `-O3`, https://godbolt.org/z/YYcq7c9v4 - we see it optimized away everything except the `functionA` print, and a print loop that hex-dumps 16 bytes of uninitialized stack space.  There is one `sub rsp, 40` at the top of the function, undone in the epilogue, no other stack-pointer movement.

Comment: @PeterCordes i guess the undefined behaviour of accessing a variable after its scope has ended throws a wrench in the optimizer.

Comment: Yes, compile-time-visible UB results in code-gen that's hard to predict, especially when it's definitely reached in `main`.  In theory the compiler could assume a function is never called in that case and emit just a `ret` or no instructions at all, so the fact that GCC chooses to do anything at all here is just based on whatever it decides about overlap of arrays and where the pointer points I guess.

Comment: @Kevin - It's not even "a wrench", but the optimizer can see that the code only ever writes to the buffer. It never reads from it (except out-of-scope, and that can never happen!), so it can just throw the buffer away.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of buff32 is the issue.
See comment from @**Ted Lyngmo**

Not knowing your question it's difficult to say but
your code should probably read like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    const uint8_t* p = NULL;
    const uint8_t BUF[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    uint8_t buff32[32] = {0};  //<<--HERE

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            memset(buff32, '\0', sizeof(buff32)); //<<---HERE
            buff32[0] = 0x5; //<<---HERE
            if (functionB(buff32))
            {
                p = buff32;
                break;
            }

            continue;

        }
        else
        {
            p = BUF;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", p[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No.
The way he has this written, every time this get's called:

if (functionB(buff32))

buff32 will be initialized, zeroed out with 0x5 at loc 0.
No way to do this in a loop from the proper scope without zeroing it out and initializing loc 0.

Without a clarifying question from him, this is correct.

Comment: The whole block involving the `memset` runs exactly once, when `i==1`.  The loop body runs twice, once for each side of the `if/else` inside it.  But sure, if that can change then you might not want to just rely on the initializer.  But that makes the initializer pointless: it could just be declared and not initialized since the only code path that references it does `memset` and sets the first element first.